# Adding Indexes? to an already existing column as they were in a wrong column

Tags: r, indexing

I have a data data frame called OECD where has a structure like below:

```
Australia            NA           -15718.17     -10664.05      7708.5129999999
Austria              NA              ..            ..          11708.76
Belguim              NA              ..            ..          -6506.86099999999
(20 more countries and some NA or .. or numbers)
notOECDEconoomy    Argentina         ..            ..           (numbers)
                   Brazil            ..            ..           (numbers)
                    china            ..            ..           (numbers)
                   (4 other countries and numbers)
```

I want to remove the "Not OECD Economies" and move the rest of the country's names in the 2nd column so the 1st column to match up with the rest of the countries. How would I do that within R with simple commands, but not using equations( not that far into coding) and also for creating graphics... how would I ignore the NA's or 0 so they don't affect the way the graphs look? Thanks

Comment: Do all non-OECD countries have the string "notOECDEconoomy" in the first column or is it empty?

Comment: the countries in the non-OECD have nothing in the first column. It came from an excel sheet and that's how it shows. I want to all the editing without touching the excel sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data frame is called `OECD`, the first column is called `country`, the second column is called `nonOECDcountry` you can use this.

```
OECD$country[!is.na(OECD$country)] <- OECD$nonOECDcountry[!is.na(OECD$country)]
```

or without the names

```
OECD[,1][!is.na(OECD[,1])] <- OECD[,2][!is.na(OECD[,1])]
```

If a name appears in your second column it will be put into the first column, if its `NA` in the second column, the first will be untouched.

After we can use this to get rid of the second column

```
OECD <- OECD[,-2]
```